# How to activate thickbox from a query string on the end of a url

Tags: jquery, html, query-string, thickbox

I'm new to programming, and this website. I have what is hopefully a quick question about using thickbox, and jquery to display an overlayed video on a website.

My problem is that I want to have the overlay displayed when someone clicks a link from an email. So the link would be something like: mywebsite.com/landingpage.html#playVideo and then everyone else who visits the web page has to click on a link to activate the overlay.

I've seen documentation about how to use js to have the overlay play for everyone who visits the site, but not for specific people from an html link.

I'm very new at this stuff and mostly function as a designer, but I'm familiar with basic programming and know enough to get myself in trouble in situations like this. I'm under a deadline and anything anyone can do to help would be appreciated. I guess you could call it a permalink to a piece of content displayed in thickbox on a page.

Thank you in advance...

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="overlay_js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="overlay_js/thickbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> var tb_pathToImage = "images/loadingAnimation.gif";</script>

<style type="text/css" media="screen">@import "css/thickbox.css";</style>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Video Overlay Example</h2>
<div id="videoDisplay" style="display:none;">
<!– start embed code copied directly from youTube.com –>
<object width="425" height="355">
  <param name="movie" value="http://cdn-static.viddler.com/flash/simple_publisher.swf?key=c28782d6&autoplay=t"></param>
  <param name="wmode" value="transparent"></param>
  <embed src="http://cdn-static.viddler.com/flash/simple_publisher.swf?key=c28782d6&autoplay=t" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="425" height="355"></embed>
</object>
<!– end embed code copied directly from youTube.com –>
</div>
<a href="#TB_inline?height=365&width=425&inlineId=videoDisplay"
  class="thickbox" title="Bill Aulet">Click here to see my video</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should highlight all of your HTML, then hit the Code button to properly format it so we can see the code.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery's plugin http://plugins.jquery.com/project/querystring to get the querystring information and then call the thickbox to load/appear in your `$(document).ready()` event :-)

Comment: I'd tell you how do load your thickbox, but there are so many "thickbox"'s out there that i'm not sure what you are using, but there should be a documentation on their website (whichever you are using) discussing how to do it :-)

Comment: yeah I have the load part going on fine. I just can't figure out this part. I saw the querystring link, but it wasn't that helpful in documenting how to implement it to capture and pass on the data. Like I said I'm pretty new to all of this and think I got in a little over my head. I'm surprised no one has wanted to do this before.